# What do we use after "got": past tense or past participle?

Tags: sentence-construction, past-tense, past-participles

> He got *burnt*.

or

> He got *burned*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are forms of the Past Participle of the verb "***burn***".  See for instance [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/burn).

I think that nowadays there is a tendency toward using regular verb forms, so "***burned***" is more frequent.  Although, there's something to be said about the difference between "*burnt*" and "*burned*", similar to those forms of the verb "*hang*".  A *toast* can be "*burnt*" when it's served to you for breakfast, but the passive voice is likely to involve the form "*burned*".

Comment: so if we have to use a verb just after 'got' we will use the past participle form of that verb?? or just past form

Comment: Past participle, if you want to produce passive voice. "Got run over", "got stuck (in traffic)", "got forgotten".